# Cuda 8 installs driver 375 even if I have 384

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, driver, ubuntu-16.04

I've been setting up a new machine for learning tensorflow and machine learning. Its running Ubuntu 16.04 with a Nvidia 970.

After installing the ppa, I upgraded to the last version of the driver, the 384.
But, when installing Cuda 8, the installation downgraded the driver to 375 version.

Why? As far as I know, 384 version should be compatible with cuda 8. 
If I do apt-get upgrade, the nvidia drivers remains in 375 but with the driver manager of Ubuntu I can install the 384 again. It is safe to upgrade again?

Comment: Not only safe, but for specific application its needed. My MATLAB-python-CUDA application needed the latests drivers so I did need to install them separately from the CUDA install. There is a tutorial somewhere in the Ubuntu.SE

Comment: This isn't a programming question and would be better asked somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Same problem reported [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1021752/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-8-downgrades-the-driver-384-59-to-375-26/). Use the *run installation files to avoid the downgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a big problem, you don't need to downgrade to 375, 384 works fine! my problem is the 384 may not work correctly with dual CUDA graphic cards.

Comment: why do you say that ?